# Entity Framework Paging Error: The wait operation timed out: AddRange

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-6, runtime-error

I am doing typical paging using EF6 C# and have my pagesize down to 30 entities (Users) when trying to list all people in one company.

I do a query to "Get all Members in Company":

```
var results = _context.MembershipUser
                .Where(x => x.Company.CompanyId == CompanyId)
                .Where(x => x.Deleted == false)
                .Skip((pageIndex - 1) * pageSize)
                .Take(pageSize);
        return new PagedList<MembershipUser>(results, pageIndex, pageSize, totalCount);
```

My PagedList work looks like this:

```
public PagedList(IEnumerable<T> source, int pageIndex, int pageSize, int total)
    {
        TotalCount = total;
        TotalPages = total / pageSize;
        if (total % pageSize > 0)
            TotalPages++;
        PageSize = pageSize;
        PageIndex = pageIndex;
        AddRange(source);
    }
```

I get the following error on the line:

```
AddRange(source);
```

The wait operation timed out
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The wait operation timed out:

> **Line 19:             AddRange(source);**

Comment: Is there an inner exception? Probably a SQL timeout.

Comment: Inner exception is empty, does not indicate sql timeout, as it happens immediately on that line. Something is wrong.